# Javascript CSS modifier triggers too early but only when run locally

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/9sLGe/

It works perfectly on JSfiddle. When I run this code locally it doesn't work the same way, what happens is the second I move down the page slider, by the smallest amount, it instantly changes the yellow navbar to position fixed, rather than doing it when it is about to be scrolled off the page.

```
var init = $('#select').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > init) {
        $('#select').css({
            top: 0,
            position: 'fixed'
        });
    } else {
        $('#select').css('position', 'relative');
    }
});
```

Is it obvious why this might be happening? There are no errors in the javascript console.

Comment: jQuery 1.3.1 is over 5 years old.

Comment: Also you're using jsfiddle incorrectly. It provides the outer HTML boilerplate for you. To include libraries, use the tools in the left-side panel. Note especially the tool that controls how the code in the JavaScript panel is included in the final page. As you have it now, that code will be placed in a "load" event handler, so it will run when the page has completely loaded. Without that, "init" will be initialized incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait your DOM to be ready. As it is not, you are probably not finding the element correctly with `$('#select')`, and your init value is messed up, as another values might be when scroll happens.

Wrap your code with this:

```
$(function () { 

  // Your code here... now taht the DOM is ready

});
```

Don't forget to cache your jQuery objects. Finding and wrapping all the time with $() must be avoided.

Please, observe that heavy handlers on input events like `scroll` are strongly disadvised.
And include your CSS before your JS.

### Extra: debouncing scroll event

Just to illustrate the concept, here, your callback won't be called on every `scroll` input:

```
var scrollTimeout,
    callback = function () {  
        /// Do your things here
    };

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if (scrollTimeout)
        clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);

    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(callback, 40);

});
```

Comment: Ah, now it works! Thank you. Can you suggest another way of doing it if putting the handler on scroll is a bad idea?

Comment: I wrote some more tips above. So: `var $window = $(window), $select = $('#select');` would be a good start. Try to debounce the event.

Comment: @Jimmy hope I've helped. If this solved your problem, please mark it as answered.